# How do I configure virtual hosts on instances?

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet, foreman

I've created a host type with `puppet` classes suitable for a web server and have successfully built a server with this.

However, I can't see how to configure a vhost on that server (without actually editing the `Apache2` configuration on the server itself).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions have a main apache configuration file that includes one or [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) directives like:

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
```

Simply deploy a configuration file for each virtual host you need to define in that directory and remember that a reload/restart of Apache is required for changes in the configuration to become effective.

Comment: I can do that, but I wanted to use Puppet/Foreman for this.

Comment: So you want to change the apache configuration without Puppet/Foreman changing *any* configuration files on the apache host? Not going to happen. Or do I misunderstand your question? The easiest is to use Puppet to drop or delete a file for each VirtualHost in such an include directory, at least compared to changing sections within a single configuration file. The alternative is found in  [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) where, once configured properly, creating a new VirtualHost becomes as simple as creating a new directory on the filesystem.

Comment: Sorry if I miscommunicated - I was hoping that I could use Puppet/Foreman to generate a configuration file for me on the web server, I just can't see how to do this. It looks like the `apache::vhost` setting in the `puppetlabs\apache` puppet module should do this:

    `apache::vhost { 'first.example.com': port => '80', docroot => '/var/www/first', }`

But, how do I even begin to use this?

Comment: What regarding apache::vhost are you confused about?